# Collection.count() on empty collection in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Collection.count() on empty collection in Mongodb is getting hanged and not returning anything
I am using Mongo java driver 3.2 . It is working from CLI.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code of your program.

Comment: DBCollection collection = mongoDb.createCollection(collectionName,new BasicDBObject());
collection.count();

Comment: JDBC Driver version is 3.3